# How to get Sample code working? Error 1452

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro, mysql-error-1452

I just started using mySQL workbench with MAMP two days ago and it's getting there. I keep getting an error about failing to update a child row and foreign constraint failure. I'm very sure the foreign constraint is needed to tie the tables together though.

```
create schema TerryLight717;
use TerryLight717;
CREATE DATABASE UniversityDB;
Use UniversityDB; CREATE TABLE student ( sid INTEGER, 
                       sname VARCHAR(25),
                       sex CHAR(1),
                       age INTEGER,
                       yeir INTEGER,
                       gpa REAL,
                       PRIMARY KEY (sid) );

CREATE TABLE dept ( dname VARCHAR(25),
                    numphds INTEGER,                    
                    PRIMARY KEY (dname) );

CREATE TABLE prof ( pname VARCHAR(25),
                    dname VARCHAR(25),                    
                    PRIMARY KEY (pname),
                    FOREIGN KEY (dname) REFERENCES dept(dname) );

CREATE TABLE course ( cno INTEGER,
                      cname VARCHAR(30),
                      dname VARCHAR(25),
                      PRIMARY KEY (cno, dname),
                      FOREIGN KEY (dname) REFERENCES dept (dname));

CREATE TABLE major ( dname VARCHAR(25),
                     sid INTEGER,
                     PRIMARY KEY (dname, sid),
                     FOREIGN KEY (dname) REFERENCES dept (dname),
                     FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student (sid));

CREATE TABLE section ( dname VARCHAR(25),
                       cno INTEGER,
                       sectno INTEGER,
                       pname VARCHAR(25),
                       PRIMARY KEY (dname, cno, sectno),
                       FOREIGN KEY (dname) REFERENCES dept (dname),
                       FOREIGN KEY (cno, dname) REFERENCES course (cno,dname),
                       FOREIGN KEY (pname) REFERENCES prof (pname));

CREATE TABLE enroll ( sid INTEGER,
                      grade float,
                      dname VARCHAR(25),
                      cno INTEGER,
                      sectno INTEGER,
                      PRIMARY KEY (sid, dname, cno, sectno),
                      FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student (sid),
                      FOREIGN KEY (dname) REFERENCES dept (dname), 
                      FOREIGN KEY (cno, dname) REFERENCES course (cno,dname),
                      FOREIGN KEY (dname, cno, sectno) REFERENCES section (dname,cno,sectno));

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES
(1, 'Jacobs, T.', 'm', 29, 5, 3.60),
(2, 'Pierson, E.', 'm', 32, 5, 3.50),
(3, 'Zeene, Ben N.', 'm', 21, 5, 3.90),
(4, 'Sulfate, Barry M.', 'm', 19, 2, 2.80),
(5, 'Form, Clara O.', 'f', 18, 1, 3.30),
(6, 'Scott, Kim J.', 'm', 20, 1, 3.80),
(7, 'Sather, Roberto B.', 'm', 22, 4, 2.20),
(8, 'Stanley, Leotha T.', 'm', 21, 3, 3.60),
(9, 'Smith, Joyce A.', 'f', 21, 4, 2.00),
(10, 'Jones, David S.', 'm', 19, 2, 3.50),
(11, 'Paul, Mary W.', 'f', 23, 5, 3.60),
(12, 'Soong, V.', 'f', 24, 5, 3.50),
(13, 'Kellerman, S.', 'f', 21, 3, 2.90),
(14, 'Cheong, R.', 'm', 25, 4, 3.00),
(15, 'Borchart, Sandra L.', 'f', 26, 5, 3.90),
(16, 'Alsberg, David J.', 'm', 25, 5, 3.50),
(17, 'Thorton, James Q.', 'm', 28, 4, 2.70),
(18, 'Gooch', 'm', 26, 1, 1.40),
(19, 'Smith, L.', 'm', 43, 4, 0.70),
(20, 'Korpel, E.', 'f', 19, 3, 3.50),
(21, 'Surk, K.', 'm', 23, 2, 2.50),
(22, 'Emile, R.', 'm', 18, 1, 2.00),
(23, 'Bomber, C.', 'f', 22, 4, 3.20),
(24, 'Carter, Jimmy', 'm', 56, 5, 3.50),
(25, 'Kissinger, Henry', 'm', 58, 5, 3.40),
(26, 'Ford, Gerald', 'm', 60, 5, 3.50),
(27, 'Anderson, P.', 'f', 18, 1, 3.20),
(28, 'Austin, G.', 'm', 25, 5, 3.50),
(29, 'Hamilton, S.', 'm', 21, 3, 2.80),
(30, 'Baker, C.', 'f', 18, 1, 3.50),
(31, 'Andrews, R.', 'm', 19, 2, 2.80),
(32, 'Liu, Huihusan', 'm', 29, 5, 3.90),
(33, 'Chao, Tsechih', 'f', 23, 5, 3.60),
(34, 'Kasten, Norman L.', 'm', 23, 2, 2.50),
(35, 'Mathews, John W.', 'm', 29, 5, 3.60),
(36, 'Burroughs, Susan S.', 'f', 18, 1, 3.00),
(37, 'Dunbar, D.', 'm', 30, 5, 3.40),
(38, 'Auen, B.', 'm', 21, 3, 2.70),
(39, 'Shoemaker, A.', 'f', 22, 4, 3.50),
(40, 'Rosemeyer, S.', 'f', 21, 3, 2.90),
(41, 'Fisher, C.', 'f', 22, 4, 3.50),
(42, 'Trude, T.', 'm', 19, 2, 2.90),
(43, 'Ksar, J.', 'm', 20, 3, 3.40),
(44, 'Moeri, S.', 'f', 20, 4, 3.20),
(45, 'June, Granson', 'f', 18, 1, 3.10),
(46, 'Micheal, Zadicki T.', 'm', 22, 2, 2.70),
(47, 'Roger, Blotter N.', 'm', 21, 3, 1.90),
(48, 'Natividad, A.', 'f', 25, 5, 4.00),
(49, 'Villa-lobos, M.', 'm', 47, 5, 3.70),
(50, 'Moomchi, B.', 'm', 32, 5, 3.50),
(51, 'Jetplane, Leaving O.', 'm', 30, 1, 0.00),
(52, 'Fy, Clara I.', 'f', 18, 2, 2.00),
(53, 'Atny, Mary H.', 'f', 26, 5, 3.80),
(54, 'Maximillian', 'm', 98, 5, 3.00),
(55, 'Glitch, R.', 'm', 19, 1, 2.80),
(56, 'Starry, J.', 'f', 22, 4, 3.30),
(57, 'Hiemerschmitz, A.', 'f', 19, 1, 2.70),
(58, 'Marshmallton', 'm', 20, 3, 3.00),
(59, 'Ziebart, F.', 'm', 22, 4, 1.80),
(60, 'Calcmity, J.', 'f', 23, 3, 2.60),
(61, 'Kennedy, Ed', 'm', 55, 3, 2.30),
(62, 'Moses, A.', 'm', 18, 1, 3.20),
(63, 'Kool, Joseph F.', 'm', 35, 5, 3.70),
(64, 'Fred, Edwin B.', 'm', 80, 5, 4.00),
(65, 'Ripper, Jack T.', 'm', 18, 1, 0.50),
(66, 'Altenhaus, Stuart', 'm', 21, 4, 2.80),
(67, 'Altenhaus, Gloria', 'f', 22, 5, 4.00),
(68, 'Crist, J.', 'm', 23, 4, 3.00),
(69, 'Heilskov, G.', 'm', 23, 4, 2.50),
(70, 'Caucutt, B.', 'm', 24, 5, 3.00),
(71, 'Mark, B.', 'm', 24, 4, 3.60),
(72, 'Barnes, J.', 'm', 45, 5, 2.30),
(73, 'Quarnty, G.', 'f', 20, 2, 4.00),
(74, 'Andrus, J.', 'f', 21, 3, 3.70),
(75, 'Jones, A.', 'f', 23, 5, 3.20),
(76, 'Zorhoff, C.', 'm', 20, 3, 3.00),
(77, 'Paull, Thomas H.', 'm', 23, 4, 2.60),
(78, 'Cool, J.', 'm', 18, 2, 2.60),
(79, 'Evert, Chris', 'f', 21, 4, 3.90),
(80, 'Connors, Jimmy', 'm', 25, 1, 0.20),
(81, 'Smith, Ike Z.', 'm', 33, 1, 1.10),
(82, 'News, Nightly', 'm', 15, 1, 1.90),
(83, 'Jones, Ivan L.', 'm', 55, 5, 3.50),
(84, 'Smith, R.', 'm', 19, 3, 2.70),
(85, 'Mayer, N.', 'f', 21, 5, 3.50),
(86, 'Gonring, J.', 'm', 21, 4, 3.70),
(87, 'Mueller, D.', 'm', 20, 3, 3.30),
(88, 'Bates, M.', 'm', 22, 4, 3.30),
(89, 'Longlastname, A.', 'f', 99, 5, 4.00),
(90, 'Zappa, F.', 'm', 16, 4, 4.00),
(91, 'Ghandi, I.', 'f', 78, 1, 3.50),
(92, 'Kirk, J.', 'm', 34, 5, 2.20),
(93, 'Andermanthenol, K.', 'm', 26, 5, 3.70),
(94, 'Uoiea, Z.', 'f', 19, 2, 3.30),
(95, 'Grzlbltz, Q.', 'm', 43, 5, 2.50),
(96, 'Birch, M.', 'f', 23, 5, 3.50),
(97, 'Morgan, D.', 'm', 18, 1, 3.50),
(98, 'Taylor, R.', 'm', 20, 3, 2.80),
(99, 'Jones, J.', 'f', 21, 1, 1.10),
(100, 'Gringo, C.', 'm', 25, 5, 2.90),
(101, 'Davis, Scott P.', 'm', 19, 3, 3.70),
(102, 'Bates, Michael L.', 'm', 22, 4, 3.40),
(103, 'Kaisler, Janet M.', 'f', 21, 4, 3.50),
(104, 'Baskett, Wayse T.', 'm', 23, 3, 2.10);

INSERT INTO dept VALUES
('Chemical Engineering',32),
('Civil Engineering',   88),
('Computer Sciences',   47),
('Industrial Engineering',  41),
('Mathematics', 129),
('Sanitary Engineering' ,3);

Insert into Prof Values
("Brian, C.",   "Computer Sciences"),
("Brown, S.",   "Civil Engineering"),
("Bucket, T.",  "Sanitary Engineering"),
("Clark, E.",   "Civil Engineering"),
("Edison, L.",  "Chemical Engineering"),
("Jones, J.",   "Computer Sciences"),
("Randolph, B.", "Civil Engineering"),
("Robinson, T.", "Mathematics"),
("Smith, S.",   "Industrial Engineering"),
("Walter, A.",  "Industrial Engineering");



INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (302, "Intro to Programming","Computer Sciences");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (310, "Thermodynamics",   "Chemical Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (310, "Intro to Garbage", "Sanitary Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (365, "City Planning",    "Civil Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (375, "Highway Engineering",  "Civil Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (461, "College Geometry 1",   "Mathematics");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (462, "College Geometry 2",   "Mathematics");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (467, "Intro to Data Structures", "Computer Sciences");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (514, "Manpower Utilization", "Industrial Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (561, "Advanced City Planning",   "Civil Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (561, "Advanced Garbage Collection5", "Sanitary Engineering");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (701, "Compiler Construction",    "Computer Sciences");
INSERT INTO course (cno, cname, dname) VALUES (726, "Nonlinear Programming",    "Computer Sciences");


INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",  310,    1,  "Edison, L.");

INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Civil Engineering", 365,    1,  "Randolph, B.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Civil Engineering", 375,    1,  "Brown, S.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Civil Engineering", 561,    1,  "Randolph, B.");

INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Computer Sciences", 302,    1,  "Jones, J.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Computer Sciences", 302,    2,  "Smith, S.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Computer Sciences", 467,    1,  "Jones, J.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Computer Sciences", 701,    1,  "Clark, E.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Computer Sciences", 726,    1,  "Brian, C.");

INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Industrial Engineering",    514,    1,  "Walter, A.");

INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Mathematics",   461,    1,  "Robinson, T.");
INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Mathematics",   462,    1,  "Robinson, T.");

INSERT INTO section (dname, cno, sectno, pname) VALUES("Sanitary Engineering",  561,    1,  "Bucket, T.");




INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics", 0);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics", 1);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(1,    3.00,   "Chemical Engineering", 310,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  2);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    2);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(2 ,3.00,  "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  3);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    3);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(3,    3.50,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Sanitary Engineering",   4);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  4);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(4,    4.00,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  5);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(5,    3.00,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  6);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(6,    3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  7);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(7,    4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  8);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(8,    4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  9);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(9,    3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  10);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  10);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(10,   2.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  11);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(11,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  12);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(12,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  13);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(13,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  14);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(14,   2.50,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  15);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(15,   3.00,   "Chemical Engineering", 310,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  16);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(16,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(16,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  17);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(17,   3.00,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  18);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(18,   2.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(18,   3.50,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  19);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(19,   3.50,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  20);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(20,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  21);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(21,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(21,   3.50,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  22);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(22,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(22,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  23);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(23,   4.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Computer Sciences",  24);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(24,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   25);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(25,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   26);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(26,   3.50,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   27);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(27,   2.50,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   28);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(28,   3.00,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   29);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(29,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    365,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(29,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(29,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   30);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(30,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   31);

INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(31,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   32);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(32,   2.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   33);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(33,   2.00,   "Civil Engineering",    365,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(33,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   34);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(34,   1.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Chemical Engineering",   35);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(35,   3.00,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  36);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(36,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  37);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(37,   3.00,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  38);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(38,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  39);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(39,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  40);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(40,   3.50,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  41);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(41,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  42);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(42,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  43);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(43,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  44);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(44,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  45);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(45,   3.00,   "Chemical Engineering", 310,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  46);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(46,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  47);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(47,   1.00,   "Civil Engineering",    365,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(47,   0.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  48);

INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(48,   1.50,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  49);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(49,   3.50,   "Chemical Engineering", 310,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(49,   3.50,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  50);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(50,   4.00,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  51);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(51,   3.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  52);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(52,   1.00,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(52,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  53);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(53,   4.00,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  54);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(54,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  55);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(55,   2.50,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  56);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(56,   2.50,   "Chemical Engineering", 310,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  57);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(57,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  58);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(58,   2.00,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  59);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(59,   3.50,   "Mathematics",  462,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  60);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(60,   2.50,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  61);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(61,   3.50,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(61,   2.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  62);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(62,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Civil Engineering",  63);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(63,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 64);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(64,   4.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(64,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 65);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 66);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(66,   1.50,   "Civil Engineering",    365,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(66,   4.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 67);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(67,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(67,   4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 68);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(68,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 69);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(69,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(69,   2.00,   "Computer Sciences",    467,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 70);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(70,   3.50,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 71);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(71,   2.50,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 72);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(72,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 73);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(73,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    375,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 74);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 75);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 76);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 77);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 78);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 79);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 80);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 81);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 82);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Industrial Engineering", 83);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    84);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    85);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    86);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    87);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    88);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    89);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    90);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    91);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    92);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    93);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    94);
INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    95);


INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    96);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(96,   4.00,   "Civil Engineering",    365,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(96,   3.00,   "Civil Engineering",    561,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    97);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(97,   3.00,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    98);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(98,   4.00,   "Industrial Engineering",   514,    1);

INSERT INTO major (dname, sid) VALUES("Mathematics",    99);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(99,   3.50,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);

INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(100,  2.00,   "Computer Sciences",    726,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(101,  4.00,   "Mathematics",  462, 1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(102,  3.50,   "Mathematics",  461,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(103,  4.00,   "Computer Sciences",    701,    1);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(104,  2.80,   "Computer Sciences",    302,    2);
INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(104,  2.60,   "Sanitary Engineering", 561,    1);
```

Comment: Pls specify exactly where you get this error. Actually, isolating the issue would even help you to find the cause yourself!

Comment: It's with the part that says INSERT INTO section VALUES. It fails to execute.

Comment: Even if section was all by itself, it still says the same thing. The datatypes are correct. The foreign keys make sense. But why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Do all of your `INSERT INTO section` fail, or only certain ones?

Comment: Yes. All of the"INSERT INTO section"  fail no matter which is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem. Your values for `prof.pname` all have a leading space, while your values for `section.pname` don't.

For what it's worth, I was taught not to use `varchar` for key fields, nor to use names or any other data that might change due to act of bureaucracy (such as a name) for key values. Following that rule tends to reduce headaches substantially.

Comment: You were right. the space in the name made a big difference. But the error 1452 is still showing up, now for the INSERT INTO major. There's no more extra space characters. Weird.

Comment: Your first `INSERT INTO major` specifies `major.sid = 0`. There's no corresponding `student` record. Do the other `INSERTs INTO major` work?

Comment: No they don't. Is there a debugger you are using to see it's 0?

Comment: Actually, when I pressed the continuing despite error, the other majors and enrolls were included. But the first one didn't work. Still 1452. How do you tell major.sid=0?

Comment: Like I said, I just eyeballed the script you posted. It looks as though the foreign key constraints are doing their job of preventing you inserting inconsistent data.

Comment: Oh I see. It was the student sid = 0. I thought it was weird that the students started at 1. This has been helpful.

Comment: It's really the sort of instinct one develops through experience. Just keep working at it.